# Firebase Phone Number Authentication: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication

**This is the kotlin code for Firebase PhoneNumberAuthentication**
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/kotlin/PhoneAuthActivity.kt 
This method **"PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber"** Give me error **"None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied"** and prompt me to create new function by saying **create extension function PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber**. Which is redundant as this method is part of **"com.google.firebase.auth.*"**. 

**Error details:**

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
public final fun verifyPhoneNumber(@NonNull p0: String, p1: Long, p2: TimeUnit!, @NonNull p3: (Runnable!) -> Unit, @NonNull p4: PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks): 
Unit defined in com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider
```

**Code:**

```
PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber, // Phone number to verify
    60, // Timeout duration
    TimeUnit.SECONDS, // Unit of timeout
    applicationContext, // Activity (for callback binding)
    mCallbacks
)
```

This code works fine in java. 
Any thoughts. What should I do. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this code was, I was initializing some fields of firebase with null which was needed as lateinit. So by removing null initialization, it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this in a fragment, make sure to change `this` with `requireActivity()`

```
  PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                    phoneNumber, // Phone number to verify
                    60, // Timeout duration
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS, // Unit of timeout
                    requireActivity(), // Activity (for callback binding)
                    callbacks) // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
```